# How to redirect output from log4j to a file?

Tags: java, log4j

I need to redirect output from Logger to a file. Output goes only to Console.

I used these configuration of **log4j.propertites**

```
# Set root logger level to INFO and appender to stdout.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# stdout is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# stdout uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=info

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/masi/logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%d{dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss}] %C{1} - %m [thread: %t]\n
log4j.appender.file.threshold=info
```

but when it didn't work, I deleted this file and used **logback.xml** instead of it.

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/home/masi/logging.log</file>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="test.suite" level="TRACE"/>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

but I still have an output to Console. 
What kind of configuration I have to do to finish my task?

Answer (score 1):

Your log4j.properites file should be configured like this. With your package specified after log4j.logger. For example if your package was your.package.name the config would look like below

```
log4j.logger.your.package.name=INFO, LOG_FILE

log4j.appender.LOG_FILE = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.File = C:/logs/log_file.log
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG_FILE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
```

The key is to tell log4j where the file is by passing

-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/[path_to_your_log4j.properties file] in your JVM args.